# MYSQL - STRIP Spaces using a procedure

Tags: mysql, function

How would I strip spaces from a string from an added column in a database by using a function in MySQL?

Something like this format.

```
CREATE FUNCTION clean_string (str VARCHAR (50))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SQL statements/queries
END
```

I'm very new with this stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write your own function, use mysql's own [replace()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to remove spaces by substituting them with an empty string:

```
replace(field_name, ' ','')
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to make a function that does this , a simple one

Comment: Why would you create one, if there is a predefined one?

Comment: To practice how to use them in MySQL.

Comment: Would it be the same way with special characters using REPLACE

Answer (score 0):

No need to write your own, you can simply **use `REPLACE`**:

```
mysql> SELECT REPLACE('foo bar qux', ' ', '');
+---------------------------------+
| REPLACE('foo bar qux', ' ', '') |
+---------------------------------+
| foobarqux                       |
+---------------------------------+
```

So you can use:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, ' ', '');
```

to remove all spaces from the specified `column` of specified `table`.

Or you can define a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION clean_string (str VARCHAR (50))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
   RETURN REPLACE(str, ' ', '');
```

and then you an update with:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = clean_string(`column`);
```

But since here you only substitute one function call for another there is not much added value here.

Comment: would this do it ?                                                                                                                                                  CREATE function clean_string(str VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
WHILE
UPDATE `articles` SET `urlsafe` = REPLACE(`urlsafe`, ' ', '');
END WHILE
END

Comment: CREATE FUNCTION clean_string (str VARCHAR (50))
RETURNS VARCHAR (50) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN REPLACE(str, ' ', ''); *syntax error missing: semi-colon*
UPDATE articles SET urlsafe = clean_string(urlsafe);
END - *extraneous input found - expected end of input*                                                                                                                                                                  Although I am getting syntax errors in MySQL workbench which say:

Comment: BEGIN and END and to run the function with a string I would use set.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although currently I have mo means to test it.